# Multiple checkbox conditional

Tags: checkboxes

I have a set of checkboxes to show content on a page. I have one instance where I'd like to show something if either checkboxes are selected. I have searched around but couldn't find how to combine multiple value. Here's what I have now

```
{% if entry.pageOptions.contains('testimonials') %}
```

And I want it to be something like:

```
{% if entry.pageOptions.contains('anotheroption|testimonials') %}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That `contains` test just does a smple string comparison. Try this:

```
{% if entry.pageOptions.contains('anotheroption')
     or entry.pageOptions.contains('testimonials') %}
```

Comment: That worked beautifully - so simple. Thank you!